# if i tap on notification QuickBlox video call not showing because root view controller change how we will show video call again In ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

call Work perfectly if app in background and open app normally works fine but when enter in app via notification tap not showing video view

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, Plist have you added code for what behaviour is expected while app is in foreground?

Comment: in quickblox video app app works fine in background (app minimize) quickblox video view shows fine but when notification trigger from firebase and tap on notification from app and open app , actually we make a controller as root so how we will show video view of quickblox again

Comment: have you added code for what behaviour is expected while app is in foreground?

Comment: let nav = UINavigationController()
        nav.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        let first = Router.shared.splashVC()
        let sceond = Router.shared.CustomTabbarVC()
        let third = Router.shared.ProviderDetailsVC()
        sceond.selectedIndex = 2
        nav.viewControllers = [first,sceond,third]
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
         i am using this code to enter app when tap on notification

Comment: using this code for video calling
 https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat-webrtc